# Check internet connection with target sdk 29 and without deprecated methods

Tags: android, deprecated, connectivity, android-connectivitymanager

I have the

```
compileSdkVersion 29
```

and

```
targetSdkVersion 29
```

in my `android` app. And to check if there is a connection I use the next code:

```
val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager?
return connectivityManager?.activeNetworkInfo?.isConnected ?: false
```

But with my `targetSdk` the `activeNetworkInfo` is deprecated. How can I check the connection status without deprecated methods and variables?

Comment: have you checked the android documentation? It says exactly what to use instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as below:

```
    val connectivityManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        val network = connectivityManager.activeNetwork
        val capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network)
        return capabilities != null && (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) || capabilities.hasTransport(
            NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR
        ))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback instead, here is the [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback.html) for documentation